# SQL counting occurrences of a certain element

Tags: mysql, sql

Right, I have a DB called pets and it has the columns

```
Name, owner Species, sex, birth and death..
```

And I want to query how many animals are of the sex Female.

My query is

```
DESCRIBE pet;

SELECT COUNT(sex) WHERE sex = 'f' as countSeX FROM pet;
```

but that does not work

Also the sex column is a `CHAR` that's why I'm searching for 'f'

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(sex) as CountSex
FROM pet
WHERE sex = 'f'
```

Comment: This did the job! Thank you! I shall accept as correct answer!

Comment: @Ceri you don't have to do `select count(sex) ...`, it is enough to do just `select count(*) ...`.

Comment: @Tomas True. I tend to do `count(1)`, but I wasn't sure if that was valid in MySql, as I mainly use T-Sql.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `AS` keyword in wrong place. `AS` keyword is used to alias `Table` or `Column` representations. Which means you can use them for tables or columns, after table name or column name.

And you also need to rearrange your query having `SELECT` keyword first, `FROM` after and `WHERE` last as this:

```
SELECT COUNT(sex) as countSeX 
FROM pet
WHERE sex = 'f'
```